# R: How to convert the date column of multiple data.frames inside a list?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, as.date

I have multiple similar data.frames inside a list which the first column is a date column. I need to use the as.Date to transform it into a timeseries which will be ploted. However it is not assigning the converted vector to the proper vector of each data.frame inside the list.

```
temporizar <- function(df){df$Semana <- as.Date(df$Semana, format = "%d/%m/%y")}
lapply(files, temporizar)

[[1]]
 [1] "2020-01-11" "2020-01-18" "2020-01-25" "2020-02-01" "2020-02-08" "2020-02-15" "2020-02-22" "2020-02-29" "2020-03-07" "2020-03-14"
[11] "2020-03-21" "2020-03-28" "2020-04-04" "2020-04-11" "2020-04-18" "2020-04-25" "2020-05-02" "2020-05-09" "2020-05-16" "2020-05-23"
[21] "2020-05-30" "2020-06-06" "2020-06-13" "2020-06-20" "2020-06-27" "2020-07-04" "2020-07-11" "2020-07-18" "2020-07-25" "2020-08-01"
[31] "2020-08-08" "2020-08-15" "2020-08-22" "2020-08-29" "2020-09-05" "2020-09-12" "2020-09-19" "2020-09-26" "2020-10-03" "2020-10-10"
[41] "2020-10-17" "2020-10-24" "2020-10-31" "2020-11-07" "2020-11-14" "2020-11-21" "2020-11-28" "2020-12-05" "2020-12-12" "2020-12-19"
[51] "2020-12-26"

[[2]]
 [1] "2020-01-11" "2020-01-18" "2020-01-25" "2020-02-01" "2020-02-08" "2020-02-15" "2020-02-22" "2020-02-29" "2020-03-07" "2020-03-14"
[11] "2020-03-21" "2020-03-28" "2020-04-04" "2020-04-11" "2020-04-18" "2020-04-25" "2020-05-02" "2020-05-09" "2020-05-16" "2020-05-23"
[21] "2020-05-30" "2020-06-06" "2020-06-13" "2020-06-20" "2020-06-27" "2020-07-04" "2020-07-11" "2020-07-18" "2020-07-25" "2020-08-01"
[31] "2020-08-08" "2020-08-15" "2020-08-22" "2020-08-29" "2020-09-05" "2020-09-12" "2020-09-19" "2020-09-26" "2020-10-03" "2020-10-10"
[41] "2020-10-17" "2020-10-24" "2020-10-31" "2020-11-07" "2020-11-14" "2020-11-21" "2020-11-28" "2020-12-05" "2020-12-12" "2020-12-19"
[51] "2020-12-26"

[[3]]
 [1] "2020-01-11" "2020-01-18" "2020-01-25" "2020-02-01" "2020-02-08" "2020-02-15" "2020-02-22" "2020-02-29" "2020-03-07" "2020-03-14"
[11] "2020-03-21" "2020-03-28" "2020-04-04" "2020-04-11" "2020-04-18" "2020-04-25" "2020-05-02" "2020-05-09" "2020-05-16" "2020-05-23"
[21] "2020-05-30" "2020-06-06" "2020-06-13" "2020-06-20" "2020-06-27" "2020-07-04" "2020-07-11" "2020-07-18" "2020-07-25" "2020-08-01"
[31] "2020-08-08" "2020-08-15" "2020-08-22" "2020-08-29" "2020-09-05" "2020-09-12" "2020-09-19" "2020-09-26" "2020-10-03" "2020-10-10"
[41] "2020-10-17" "2020-10-24" "2020-10-31" "2020-11-07" "2020-11-14" "2020-11-21" "2020-11-28" "2020-12-05" "2020-12-12" "2020-12-19"
[51] "2020-12-26"
```

How can I properly convert to as.Date each date vector of each data.frame inside a list?

PS: I'm brazilian, so "temporizar" mean "change into time" and "Semana" means "Week"

Comment: Use this function `temporizar <- function(df){df$Semana <- as.Date(df$Semana, format = "%d/%m/%y");df}`

Comment: Unfortunately it remains as a factor
`..$ Semana     : Factor w/ 51 levels "01/02/20","01/08/20",..: 16 28 40 1 12 24 36 48 10 22...`

Comment: Check your date format, but with the `return(df)`suggested by @RonakShah it should work. Would you have an example of df$Semana ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you used read.delim or read.table to read in the file, and by default, character columns are factors.

Try something like this:

```
DATES = as.character(
seq(as.Date("01/01/92",format="%d/%m/%y"), 
as.Date("31/12/92",format="%d/%m/%y"), 
length.out=100))

files = lapply(1:5,function(i)
data.frame(Semana = sample(DATES,5),value=runif(5)))
```

So you should check:

```
 str(files[[1]])
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Semana: Factor w/ 5 levels "1992-02-17","1992-05-31",..: 4 1 5 2 3
 $ value : num  0.892 0.551 0.457 0.957 0.453
```

Then the function below should work

```
temporizar <- function(df){
df$Semana <- as.Date(as.character(df$Semana))
df
}
lapply(files, temporizar)
```

Comment: Didn't work as well. It converts correctly, but it doesn't assign it to the actual objet 'files'. It works in the console:
`'data.frame': 51 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ Semana     : Date, format: "2020-01-11" "2020-01-18" "2020-01-25" "2020-02-01" ...`
However it doesn't change the 'files' object.

Comment: you have to reassign it back. files <- lapply(files,temporizar)

Comment: Thanks! You're right. Sometimes we miss very trivial thing lol

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with a *for* loop.

```
for(i in names(files)){
  files[[i]]$Semana <- as.Date(files[[i]]$Semana, format = "%d/%m/%y")
  print(i)
  str(files[[i]])
}
```

I used *print(i)* and *str(files[[i]])* as checkpoints for the convertion. It looks like it worked. Thank you very much for your answers.